# Display custom image and link to a sectionList item on react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-sectionlist

I'm a newbie on react-native.
I want to build personalized data from array to populate sectionLists.

My actual code, extracted from [react-native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist) is

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, SectionList, StatusBar } from "react-native";

const DATA = [
  {
    title: "Main dishes",
    data: ["Pizza", "Burger", "Risotto"],
  },
  {
    title: "Sides",
    data: ["French Fries", "Onion Rings", "Fried Shrimps"]
  },
  {
    title: "Drinks",
    data: ["Water", "Coke", "Beer"]
  },
  {
    title: "Desserts",
    data: ["Cheese Cake", "Ice Cream"]
  }
];

const Item = ({ title }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
  </View>
);

const App = () => (
  <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
    <SectionList
      sections={DATA}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item} />}
      renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
        <Text style={styles.header}>{title}</Text>
      )}
    />
  </SafeAreaView>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: StatusBar.currentHeight,
    marginHorizontal: 16
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: "#f9c2ff",
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 32,
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24
  }
});

export default App;
```

Here, we have only 2 dimensions to data array. I want to personalize that DATA array sending an image source, and a link to a screen on itemclick, for example.

I mean, I have actually title, data on DATA array. I want to add image and link columns to this DATA array and I want to have a solution to parse it in order to associate the link to props and display an image by its source content on image field.

Could you please tell me how to present that for the array and render it ?

Thanks.

EDIT :

I want to add 2 columns image and link on the DATA array like that :

```
const DATA = [
  {
    title: "Main dishes",
    data: ["Pizza", "Burger", "Risotto"],
    image: [require('../assets/Aquarium.png'), require('../assets/Aquarium.png'), require('../assets/Aquarium.png')]
    link: ["Pizza", "Burger", "Risotto"]
  },
  {
    title: "Sides",
    data: ["French Fries", "Onion Rings", "Fried Shrimps"]
    image: [require('../assets/Aquarium.png'), require('../assets/Aquarium.png'), require('../assets/Aquarium.png')]
    link: ["FrenchFries", "OnionRings", "FriedShrimps"]
  },
  {
    title: "Drinks",
    data: ["Water", "Coke", "Beer"]
    image: [require('../assets/Aquarium.png'), require('../assets/Aquarium.png'), require('../assets/Aquarium.png')],
    link: ["Water", "Coke", "Beer"]
  },
  {
    title: "Desserts",
    data: ["Cheese Cake", "Ice Cream"]
    image: [require('../assets/Aquarium.png'), require('../assets/Aquarium.png')]
    link: ["CheeseCake", "IceCream"]
  }
];
```

And I want to change my code like this to present image and link to a stackscreen name but it gives me errors.

```
return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
          <SectionList
            sections={DATA}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
            renderItem={({ item }) => 
              <TouchableWithoutFeedback 
                activeOpacity={0.4}
                onPress={ () => navigation.navigate(item.link)}>
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', textAlign: 'left', fontSize: 15, backgroundColor:'transparent', marginTop: 15, marginBottom: 15}}>
                  <Image source={item.image}/>
                  <Item title={item.title} />
                  
                </View>
              </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            }
            renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
              <View>
                <Text style={styles.header}>{title}</Text>
              </View>
            )}
          />
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
```

Could you please help me ?

Comment: Do you want to show an image for every item or every section? It would be nice if you provide the actual data shape you'll use

Comment: I want to display a different icon for every item. Now I’m just discovering a way to present data.

Comment: I added data you asked me

Comment: What errors do you get?